# how to highlight the selected thumb image of a image gallery, when we click on it?

Tags: jquery

Im  a beginner in jquery, i created a simple image slider. code is like this

```
     $(function() {
        $(".specialimage").click(function() {

        var image = $(this).attr("rel");
        $('#specialimage').hide();
        $('#specialimage').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#specialimage').html('<img src="' + image + '"/>');
        return false;
        });
        });
```

Web site is : http://ymaclub.com/test/special.html

the image gallery is working fine, but its not highlighting the selected thumb image when we click a particular thumb image of the gallery..

Can any one please help me **how to highlight the selected thumb image of a image gallery,  when we click on it?**

Comment: By highlight you mean?

Comment: When we click the thumb its needed to show clicked (maybe a different thumb image there )  This is the site : http://ymaclub.com/test/special.html.. can you please have a look when you get time?

Comment: Hi, Pravin, you have to add a classes to clicked thumb, that is the way you can do this. jquery it self will not do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is the thumb the `$(".specialimage")`, if so you can just add a new class in your click function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var thumbs = $(".specialimage");

    thumbs.click(function() {
      thumbs.removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');

      var imageUrl = $(this).attr("rel");
      $('#specialimage').hide('fast', function() {
        $(this).html('<img src="' + imageUrl + '"/>').fadeIn('slow');
      });

      return false;
    });
});
```

Then add your highlight css for the class `selected`

Comment: Hi thanks for your help :) , thumb is not "".specialimage"" http://ymaclub.com/test/special.html can please have a look?

Comment: hi the above code should work fine with what you have, you will just need to add a style for `.selected` to highlight the selected thumbnail.  Also you may want to set some dimensions on `#specialimage` so the page doesn't "jump" when you click on a new image

Comment: yes i tried but not sure why its not working, http://ymaclub.com/test/file.zip can you please have a look ?

Comment: try wrapping the js in the $(document).ready() - edited the above answer

Comment: wow its working thanks so much :) you have any idea why the large image is jumping when we click on the thumb?

Comment: It's because you are actually removing the image from the div as you are recreating a new one every time.  Sometimes, if the image hasn't been loaded, the broswer will have to reload it and that is what is causing the box to close - if you gave `#specialimage` set dimensions of the size of your image it would stop the jumping effect

Answer (score 1):

create a css class for selected thumb say **thumbSelected**.. and add that class when clicked on the thumb...

try this

**updated jquery**

```
    $(".specialimage").click(function() {
      $(".specialimage img").removeClass('thumbSelected'); //first remove existing thumbSelected class
      $(this).find('img').addClass('thumbSelected'); // add class to clicked thumb
      var image = $(this).attr("rel");
      $('#specialimage').hide().fadeIn('slow').html('<img src="' + image + '"/>');
      return false;
    });
```

**CSS**

```
 .thumbSelected{
    border:1px solid red;  //this is just an example.. you can use any css properties here
 }
```

Comment: HI thank you for your help, but its not working http://ymaclub.com/test/special.html - this is the image gallery. can you please have a look?

Comment: i updated the code.. you are using the old code.. there should be img instead of a try that out

Comment: yes did but still have problem..http://ymaclub.com/test/file.zip can you please have look to this files?